# Create ShellObject using WindowsAPICodePack

Tags: c#, shell

I have the following ParsingName for a ShellObject

`"::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\\0\\::{E2E7934B-DCE5-43C4-9576-7FE4F75E7480}"`

How do I create a new ShellObject based on this value?

I have tried (where path = above string)

```
ShellObject obj = ShellObject.FromParsingName(path)
```

But I get an exception arguments not valid.

Comment: That looks like 2 names?  What is the name supposed to represent?

Comment: It's a control panel item. The ShellObject API returned me a ParsingName as described. When I use the same ParsingName to create a new ShellObject it fails.

Comment: try just ::{E2E7934B-DCE5-43C4-9576-7FE4F75E7480} ? (date & time)

Comment: Makes no difference ShellObject.FromParsingName still fails

Comment: The calling function that fails is SHCreateItemFromParsingName with 80070057

Answer (score 1):

First remove the double \\ in your path to single one like \.
Second try putting shell: in front of your path. 
Like this: 
`string path = "shell:::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{E2E7934B-DCE5-43C4-9576-7FE4F75E7480}";` 
`ShellObject obj = ShellObject.FromParsingName(path);`